# Ragged 2D int array pyramid with Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d

Write the code required to allocate a ragged 2-D int array such that the first row has space to store 1 value, the second row can store 2 values, the third row has space to store 3 values, etc. up until the 50th row which has space to store 50 values.

I know for the above question I have to essentially create a pyramid with a 2 dimensional array. I don't really know how to manipulate 2D arrays, any help will be great. This is my code thus far, not sure how to allocate space like the question above says:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Ragged2D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] boo = new int[50][];


        for(int i = 0; i < boo.length; i++){

            for(int k = 0; k< boo[i].length; k++){

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boo));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you initialize a row of the 2D array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] boo = new int[50][];


    for(int i = 0; i < boo.length; i++){
        boo[i] = new int[i+1]; // initialize the i'th row to have i+1 elements
        for(int k = 0; k< boo[i].length; k++){
            boo[i][k] = ...
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(boo)); // this change is required to print 2D array
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind initializing boo[i] with int[i+1]?

Comment: @userb `i` iterates from 0 to boo.length-1, but you want the first row to have 1 column and the last row to have boo.length column. Therefore, the first row (with i=0) should have 1 (i+1) columns, the second row (with i=1) should have 2 (i+1) columns, ... , and the last row (with i=boo.length-1) should have boo.length (i+1) columns.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need

```
int[][] boo = new int[50][];

    for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
        boo[i] = new int[i+1];
    }
```

This way boo[0] can contain 1 element (boo[0][0]), boo[1] can contain 2 elements (boo[0][0] and boo[0][1]) etc.

Comment: I don't get it. wouldn't that just make boo have more rows not columns?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure what difference do you see. I mean I might not fully understand what you want to achieve

Comment: It worked, by initializing it but I'm just trying to understand how it works behind the scene. It seems to me it just adds more rows. But it definitely does more than that, since it worked. And was just trying to get the logic behind it

Comment: Well int[][] boo = new int[50][0] declares an array with 50 rows. Each row of that array is another array which hasn't been yet declared. This is why you can do for example boo[27] = new int[x] where x is pretty much any number you want (because you're declaring this array now - you won't be able to change that afterwards).

Comment: Also remember that in Java declaring 2d array like int[][] boo = new int[5][5] is the same as declaring it as int[][] boo = new int[5] and then boo[0] = new int[5]; boo[1] = new int[5]; boo[2] = new int[5]; and so on.